# Setting multiple objects with angular (select)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following structure:

```
period: {
    startDate: new Date(),
    endDate: new Date()
}
```

Now with my select tag I should be able to set both startDate and endDate. This is because my select shows an option of startDate "-" endDate as shown beneath:

```
<select id="periodId" ng-model="selectedPeriod">
  <option value="{{ period.startDate}}|{{period.endDate }}" ng-repeat="period in periods">{{ period.startDate | date : 'dd-MM-yyyy' }} - {{ period.endDate | date : 'dd-MM-yyyy' }}</option>
</select>
```

That way I should have my selectedDate in the format specified in my first code example.

I tried using an ng-change but that didn't work.

Comment: You should use `<select multiple>`

Comment: An what is your problem? "that didn't work" : what didn't work?

Comment: i used ng-change="callFunction()" where the function would take the value of the option (option="{{period.startDate}}|{{period.endDate}}") there i would split on the | and set the correct startDate and endDate.

Comment: Can you give the plunker version of your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) if you want to bind to an object. From Angular's documentation:

> > In many cases, ngRepeat can be used on  elements instead of ngOptions to achieve a similar result. However, ngOptions provides some benefits such as reducing memory and increasing speed by not creating a new scope for each repeated instance, as well as providing more flexibility in how the 's model is assigned via the select as part of the comprehension expression. *ngOptions should be used when the  model needs to be bound to a non-string value. This is because an option element can only be bound to string values at present.*

So, in your case:

```
<select id="periodId" ng-model="selectedPeriod"
    ng-options="period as ((period.startDate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy') + ' - ' + (period.endDate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy')) for period in periods">
</select>
```

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qkH1ubxkcPpVqoCjGH5Z?p=preview)